# Index error with Javascript parser

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy and the Javascript parsing module 'slimit' to look for a particular Javascript item within pages that I am crawling, like so:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from slimit import ast
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor


def get_fields(data):
    parser = Parser()
    tree = parser.parse(data)
    return {getattr(node.left, 'value', ''): getattr(node.right, 'value', '')
            for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree)
            if isinstance(node, ast.Assign)}


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goal2"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/"]


    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(''),deny=('')]

    def parse_item(self, response):

        script = sel.xpath('//div[@id="team-stage-stats"]/following-sibling::script/text()')
        if script is not None:
            script = script.extract()[0]
```

This works fine as long as the item is found on a page crawled. If it isn't I get an error that the list index is out of range. I thought the 'is not None:' statement would sort this, but it appears that this is not the case.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Not terribly familiar with scrapy, but other xpath engines I'm familiar with will give you an empty list `(ie `[]`)` if your expression doesn't match.

Comment: @roippi hi, thanks for replying. what syntax would i need there then? something like 'if script is not []' im guessing will not work?

Comment: just `if script:` should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your `xpath` call is returning an empty list instead of `None`. Changing your check to

```
if script is not None and len(script) > 0:
```

should fix the issue. Or more simply, you could rely on the truthiness with just

```
if script:
```

Since both `None` and `[]` are falsy values. This does the same thing as its longer counterpart.